# Problem integration Adsense in Google Sheets

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, adsense

I can add a script in an existing sheet using the script editor and provide access to the AdSense API, as described in the official documentation: [AdSense Management API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/adsense). Once enabled the AdSense API in the script editor, the first time you execute the *generateReport()* function, it asks for providing permission, and if it is granted, it creates a new sheet with the AdSense report.

This is the code, where the function returns a test number if everything is OK (in this case 55):

```
/**
* Returns a test number.
*
* @return {Number} a test number.
* @customfunction
*/

function generateReport() {    
    var adClientId="XXXXXXXXXX"
    // Prepare report.
    var today = new Date();
    var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    var timezone = Session.getTimeZone();
    var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(today, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    var report = AdSense.Reports.generate(startDate, startDate, {
      // Specify the desired ad client using a filter.
      filter: ['AD_CLIENT_ID==' + escapeFilterParameter(adClientId)],
      metric: ['PAGE_VIEWS', 'AD_REQUESTS', 'AD_REQUESTS_COVERAGE', 'CLICKS',
               'AD_REQUESTS_CTR', 'COST_PER_CLICK', 'AD_REQUESTS_RPM',
               'EARNINGS'],
      dimension: ['DATE'],
      // Sort by ascending date.
      sort: ['+DATE']
    });

    if (report.rows) {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('AdSense Report');
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

      // Append the headers.
      var headers = report.headers.map(function(header) {
        return header.name;
      });
      sheet.appendRow(headers);

      // Append the results.
      sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length)
      .setValues(report.rows);

      Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s',
                 spreadsheet.getUrl());

      return 55;
    } else {
      Logger.log('No rows returned.');
    }
}
```

However, if I try to execute the same function in the existing sheet instead of the script editor, the function is failing, reporting that calling the *generateReport()* and accessing the report in AdSense requires login. For accessing the function in the sheets, a cell is double clicked and the function is called using *=generateReport()* and failing in the execution by the login issue.

I cannot find any place in the sheet to provide access to AdSense API, as it was made on the script editor, so how grant permission?

Comment: So my understanding is that when you execute the code through the editor it works normally, but on the sheet you have no permission? 
Have you tried to make a trigger and see if that works? Can you share a snippet of your code?

Comment: Right, that's exactly what is happening. I have updated the answer with the code. What is required is using the functions in certain variable cells, so access from the sheet and not from the script editor is mandatory. The code is not yet finished, only reproducing the sample from documentation. I will try the trigger